# Installation of .msi rolls back

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am attempting to install a new version of Calibre, a free reader. I must also note that the current version that is installed (2.70) cannot be uninstalled because there is no entry in Windows Installed programs list. Weird. I keep getting the error:

```
=== Logging started: 11/21/2016  14:20:18 ===
Error 1719. The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.
=== Logging stopped: 11/21/2016  14:21:00 ===
```

Verbose logging produces a HUGE log file, so I refrain from posting that here.

I have already gone to Microsoft web site and tried the fix from here with no luck, same result:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Help?

Comment: Which version/edition of Windows?  Do other MSIs install correctly?

Comment: "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed." seems to be the core issues.

Can you try the following four commands?
`%windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /unregister`  
`%windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /regserver`   
`%windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /unregister`  
`%windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /regserver`  

Then do a full reboot with `shutdown -s`/

Comment: I already did all of the commands you refer to. It did not solve the issue. Windows 7 SP1. Other .msi files do NOT install either. Same issue.

Comment: I also noticed that my disk space was dramatically shrinking. So I downloaded TreeSize Free and ran a scan. System Volume Information folder increases with a 6.5GB file each time an install is attempted. And the size of this file increases with each .msi install attempt. Historical sizes of the files in SVI folder are (just during last few days) from 366mb incrementally larger up to 6.5GB (yesterday). I have stopped attempting to run any .msi installs to troubleshoot the issue. I can share TreeSize free report offline if desired.

Comment: Error 1719. The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
Product: calibre -- Error 1719. The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support 

personnel for assistance.
Action ended 20:44:45: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.